# how to find the weights in a portfolio?

Tags: portfolio-management, risk-management, covariance, expected-return, finance-mathematics

Compute the weights in a portfolio consisting of two kinds of stocks if the expected return on the portfolio is to be $E(K_v)=10\%$, given the following information on the returns on stock 1 and 2:
$$
\begin{matrix}
Scenerio & probability & return K_1 & return K_2 \\
\omega_1 & 0.1 & -10\% & 10\% \\
\omega_2 & 0.3 & 0\% & -5\% \\
\omega_3 & 0.6 & 15\% & 20\% \\
\end{matrix}
$$

I found $E(K_1)=8\%$ and $(E_2)=11.5\%$ so $0.08\omega_1 + 0.115\omega_2 = 0.1$
But I don't know how to find the weights? I think the covariance will help me so I found that to equal $0.0109$ but I am not sure if it is correct and I don't know how to find the weights?

Comment: your second constraint is $w_1 + w_2=1$.

Comment: Nothing is said about variance, so choose weights that minimize your portfolio standard deviation for a expected return of 10%

Comment: there has to be a way to figure that out, it can't just be plug in numbers for $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ to guess the correct answer right?

Comment: There are two variables and two constraints. Solve them simultaneously. What more do you want?

Comment: $\omega_1 = 42.86\%$ and $\omega_2 = 57.14\%$, I didn't realize it was that simple, the textbook was telling me to find standard deviation and covariance and use those to find the weights.

Comment: @Neeraj How is this basic? it involves linear algebra and calculus right?

Comment: @Neeraj So [this](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/11231/yield-to-maturity/11233#11233) is basic?

Comment: @idknuttin Your question is basic of basics.  Further, it is more like a assignment question.  Any basic introductory book of finance provide formulae of expected return and risk.  Why donot you follow any good standard text book?

Answer (score 1):

**In case of 2 securities, each and every combination of portfolio lies on efficient frontier**. In your question, you have given to achieve expected return of exactly 10%. So, we have
$$E(R_p)=w_1E(K_1) + w_2E(K_2)=0.10 \tag{1}$$
subject to: $$w_1 + w_2=1 \tag{2}$$
Solve your equation 1 and 2 to get $w_1$ and $w_2$. **Resulting weights would lead to minimum variance for given expected return**. Variance of portfolio: 
$$var(R_p)= w_1^2 \sigma_{K_1}^2 + w_2^2 \sigma_{K_2}^2 + 2 w_1 w_2\, cov(K_1, K_2) $$
where, $\sigma_{K_1}$ and $\sigma_{K_2}$ are standard deviation of $K_1$ and $K_2$ respectively.